# is there any way to access hook function on parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to generate form using JSON .I am able to render that form using JSON. I am using below library to render form .

https://github.com/adiathasan/mui-react-hook-form-plus

But I am trying to access all method on parent component getValue , setvalues, setValues . is it possible ? these methods are forms methods or present in child component .
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-lake-6h6cdq?file=/src/formbuilder.tsx

parent component

```
export default function App() {
//const methods = useHookForm();
const onChange = () => {
//console.log("000000", methods?.getValues());
// am trying
//methods.setValue("firstName", "asdasd");
};

// const { registerState, handleSubmit } = methods;

const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
console.log(data);
};
return (
<FormBuilder
jsonSchema={json}
defaultValue={defaultValue}
onSubmitHandler={onSubmit}
functionHandler={{
onChange: onChange
}}
/>
);
```

**On Dropdown change i am calling on change method . I want to set some value using setvalue or setvalues function is it possible**

```
const onChange = () => {
//console.log("000000", methods?.getValues());
// am trying
//methods.setValue("firstName", "asdasd");
};
```

Comment: Probably not enough info on this one to suggest an appropriate fix, but I'll fire off two you can look into: 1) Create the form methods using `useHookForm` higher up and use the provided [context/provider](https://github.com/adiathasan/mui-react-hook-form-plus#example-for-nested-component) to pass it throughout your form. 2) Change your function handler so that it is passed the form methods as a parameter i.e. `(formMethods) => { formMethods.setValue("firstName", "I AM A BANANA")}`